# What processor does the Cisco SRP500 Series router use

Tags: router

Can someone tell me which processor is used in the [Cisco SRP 500](http://www.cisco.com/go/srp500) series routers, specifically the SRP547w?

I've been trawling Google, the Cisco website and documentation but can't seem to find any details.

I'm trying to establish if this hardware is capable of being flashed with OpenWRT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer was provided by Andrew Hickman, engineer at Cicso, over at the Cisco support forum:

> Hi Benn,
>
> The SRP520 has a 800MHz Marvell processor.  Per the data sheet, this has 32MB flash and 64MB of DRAM.
>   The SRP540 has a 1.2GHz processor and twice as much memory.
>
> Cheers
>
> Andy

https://supportforums.cisco.com/message/3499141#3499141

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any information online (on Cisco's website or elsewhere) about the SRP547w's processor. You might be able to contact Cisco directly and ask for more detailed technical specifications than are available on their website.

I am fairly certain that the router will not be supported by OpenWRT. The [Table of Hardware page on their wiki](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start) states:

> A very reliable way to check for existing support, is to take a look at http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/. The devices are sorted by target rather then manufacturer and if there is an image for the device, it should work

Unfortunately, neither the snapshots nor the various linked wiki pages contain any information about the SRP500 series, or any other similar Cisco small business router.